# Is it better to use recursion or iteration to separate the even and odd length strings in a C++ linked list?

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration

Good morning. Is it better to use recursion or iteration to separate the even and odd length strings in a C++ linked list?

Better means 1) Robustness 2) Cross Platform Windows/Linux/Unix Portability 3) Worst Case Run Time performance.

```
cSinglyLinkedList* SeparateOddandEvenlLengthStrings(cSinglyLinkedList* list){
    cSinglyLinkedList* Retval(NULL);
    char* Temp(NULL);
    if (list == NULL || list->Head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    if (list && list->Current && list->Current->Next == NULL){
        return list;
    }
    if (list->Iterate()){
        Temp = list->Current->String;

        Retval = SeparateOddAndEvenLengthStrings(list);

        if ((strlen(Temp) % 2) == 0){
            Retval->Remove(Temp);       
            Retval->Add(Temp);
        }
        return Retval;
    }
    return NULL;
}

class cSinglyLinkedList {
private:
    struct SinglyLinkedInfo{
        SinglyLinkedInfo* Next;
        char* String;
        SinglyLinkedInfo(void){
            Next =  0;
            String= 0;
        }
    } Item;
    SinglyLinkedInfo *Head, *Current; 
    int Count;
    void ClearStrings(void);

public:
    cSinglyLinkedList(void);
    ~cSinglyLinkedList(void);
    bool Add(const char *string1);
    void Remove(const char *string1);
    bool RestartIterator(void);
    bool Iterate(void);
    int GetCount(void);
    SinglyLinkedInfo* GetHead(void);
    SinglyLinkedInfo* GetCurrent(void);
    void Trace(const char *title_);
};

inline bool cSinglyLinkedList::RestartIterator(void) {
    Current=Head;
    return (Current!=0);
}

inline bool cSinglyLinkedList::Iterate(void) {
    if (Current==0){
        Current=Head;
    } else if (Current){ 
        Current = Current->Next;
    }
    return (Current!=0);
}
inline SinglyLinkedInfo *cSinglyLinkedList::GetHead(void) {
    return Head;
}
inline SinglyLinkedInfo *cSinglyLinkedList::GetCurrent(void) {
    return Current;
}
cSinglyLinkedList::cSinglyLinkedList(void) {
    Head=Current=0;
    Count=0;
}
cSinglyLinkedList::~cSinglyLinkedList(void) {
    ClearStrings();
}
void cSinglyLinkedList::ClearStrings(void) {
    SinglyLinkedInfo* nextCurrent;
    Current=Head;
    while (Current!=0) {
        nextCurrent = Current->Next;
        delete[] Current;
        Current=nextCurrent;
    }
    Head=Current=0;
    Count=0;
}
void cSinglyLinkedList::Remove(const char* string1_) {
    SinglyLinkedInfo* Prev(NULL);
    RestartIterator();
    Current = Head;
    while (Current!=0) {
        if (strcmp(Current->String,string1_)==0){       
            if (Prev){
                Prev->Next = Current->Next;
            } else{
                Head = Current->Next;
            }
            delete [] Current;
            break;
        }
        Prev=Current;
        Current=Current->Next;
    }
    RestartIterator();
    Count -= 1;
}

bool cSinglyLinkedList::Add(const char *string1_){ 
    SinglyLinkedInfo* newElement = (SinglyLinkedInfo*)new char[sizeof(SinglyLinkedInfo)];
    memset(newElement, '\x0', sizeof(SinglyLinkedInfo)); 
    newElement->String = new char[sizeof(char*)];
    memcpy(newElement->String, &string1_, sizeof(char*));
    newElement->String = (char*)string1_; 
    newElement->SinglyLinked = new cPCRE();
    newElement->SinglyLinked->SetOptions(PCRE_CASELESS);
    if (newElement->SinglyLinked->Compile(string1_) == 0){
        return false;
    }
    if (Head==0) {
        Head = newElement;

    } else {
        SinglyLinkedInfo* Temp(NULL);

        Temp = Head;

        while (Temp != 0 && Temp->Next != 0){
            Temp = Temp->Next;
        }

        Temp->Next = newElement;
    }

    Count++;
    return true;
}
void cSinglyLinkedList::Trace(const char *title_) {
    int i=0;

    if (title_!=0)
        printf("%s:\n",title_);

    if (RestartIterator()) {
        do {
            printf(" %d: %s\n",i++,GetString());
        } while (Iterate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I don't think this question is "bad" (not worthy of closing, not even worthy of a downvote), but it's a good example of how _not_ to ask a question.  The title is good, but the "wall of code" will be off-putting to most users.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, In this case, Better means 1) Robustness 2) Cross Platform Windows/Linux/Unix Portability 3) Worst Case Run Time performance. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Ok, please edit your question to include those requirements! ;)

Comment: @Chad, The reason I added the wall of code is to see if anyone can improve the code for afuture code review I have next week. Thank you for your nice edit!!

Comment: If you _really_ want a code review, simply use `std::list` instead (the question _is_ tagged `c++`, after all).  Then simply iterate the list using `iterators` or an appropriate function call found in `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: @Chad, Our project director does not want to use Standard Template Library <List> and <algorithm) because of cross platform Windows/Linux?UNIX portability issues surrounding different implementations of STL in Windows, RedHat Linux, Solaris Unix, IBM AIX and HPUX. Thank you for your coment

Comment: if the work can not be easily broken into two parts, recursion will just lead to a stack-overflow easily.

Comment: @ahenderson, We recently studied the PCRE library code which uses recursion to process regular expressions. The PCRE author uses recursion heavily but lets the user of the pCRE library specifythe maximum stack depth. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Frank: You would have to be using some pretty old/broken compilers to have any significant portability issue with STL nowadays.  It's certainly not a good reason to reject a core part of the C++ standard out of hand!

Comment: @Boann I take it you never seriously programmed in any functional programming language? Comparing recursion to an iterative approach purely based on experience with Java or C# is not really fair. That's like evaluating iteration based on x86 assembly. There's a reason why lots of procedural languages become more and more functional as they progress (C# being the most obvious example here I can think of). In the end if you're writing in C++ the iterative solution is usually the idiomatic so pick that one, but that doesn't make it "better" in general.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, in the case of Linux and UNIX, GCC and STL are very portable. On the other hand, native Solaris Unix ,AIX and HPUX compilers may use different versions of STL . Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: "Different versions"?  To be fair, I'm not familiar with compilers for those platforms, but I would guess that if there *are* any observable differences, they'd be in more exotic areas of the standard.  This doesn't seem a good justification for wasting time implementing standard routines (and all the associated test/debugging required)!  I would rather deal with edge-cases as and when they arise.  Honestly, this sounds like poor software engineering on the part of your manager (although I appreciate you may be able to do little about it!).

Comment: @Frank Can you give me a single example of the standard library that's implemented differently between Linux and Solaris? This seems *extremely* unlikely to say the least..

Comment: @Voo, apparently you've never used the Solaris compilers. The default standard library is ancient and doesn't use such "modern" features as partial specialization and member templates, and iostream classes are not templates. It ships with **two** alternative stdlib implementations (STLport and stdcxx) to overcome the shortcomings in the default RW-derived stdlib. The solution is to not use the default lib, but you're entirely wrong to say there are no significant differences.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Just... wow.  So basically you're not writing C++ when using that compiler?!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the _compiler_ supports those features, but the default stdlib doesn't take advantage of them (the stdlib implementation has barely changed since the days when the compiler didn't support them, for backward compatibility reasons with paying customers' old codebases.) Again, the answer is to use one of the bundled alternative stdlib implementations, unless you are stuck on an ancient codebase that relies on the old stdlib.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Thank you for your comment. On Solaris Native C++ compiler, how does one specify how to use the proper alternative STL library.

Comment: `-library=stlport4` for STLport, `-library=stdcxx4` for the Apache stdcxx library (probably the best option), or `-library=Cstd` for the default one (which shouldn't be used without very good reason). See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/bkakg.html and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/gkcai.html

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely, Thank you for your answer. I am going to get a bite for lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion that isn't "bounded" [1] is definitely a bad thing. What would happen if someone gave your function the complete works of shakespeare as the input (and I mean ALL the books, not "The complete works of shakespeare", which is about 32 characters long).

The problem with unbounded recursion is that it blows up in a way you can't recover from, because once the stack has been completely used up, there is nothing anyone can do but to kill the process. You can't call a function to say "Sorry, I ran out of stack", because that uses stackspace!

[1] or such that you can reasonably say that it's going to be OK with a given number of recursion calls - say for example a reasonably balanced binary tree can search through 4 billion entries at 32 recursion levels, so if your database is not going to be more than a few million entries [and there are guards against pathological cases were all the nodes end up in a linked list down the left or right side of the tree], then you can say it's OK.

Comment: We recently studied the C language PCRE(Perl Compatible Regular Expression) library code which uses recursion to process regular expressions. The PCRE author uses recusrion heavily but lets the user of the pCRE library specifythe maximum stack depth. Thank you for your comment

Comment: Yes, but I bet the maximum recursion depth in a regular expression is the length of the string - and regular expressions tend to not the fantastically long. As far as I can see, your function recurses for every word in the input, which could be several thousand without much difficulty - even ONE work of Shakespeare would be several thousand words, right? Would your code cope with nearly 900000 words in the input?

Comment: Yes, I agree that 900000 input words would break the maximum stack depth of Windows and Linux operating systems. Thank you.

Comment: I will try to accept your answer in 5 minutes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Although it may not matter in the end because of [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), iterative approach to linked list processing is more idiomatic, at least as far as C++ is concerned. Unlike recursive approach, iterative one will not result in stack overflow even if your compiler does not apply tail call optimization.

Comment: +1 The word "idomatic" conveys that the iterative approach will be more familiar and readable to typical C++ programmers.  Despite my fondness for all things recursive, it's easier to code/debug an iterative procedure when the outcomes are as simple as splitting up a list.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Thank you for your answer. I agree that iteration will solve the stack overflow problem. However, The recursive approcah is simpler to read and involves less code than the iterative approach.

Comment: @Frank You would be surprised at the number of long-time practicing programmers who thoroughly misunderstand recursion, down to dismissing it as somehow "inefficient"! Even if you can save a few lines of code with recursion over iterations, when your underlying data structure structure is linear, as a rule you are better off with iterations.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well in C++ that is - but only because it's the idiomatic thing to do there. Just as you wouldn't write the iterative version in say scheme. Performancewise a good compiler should generate pretty much the same code. And implementing things like cache-oblivious algorithms iterative sounds to me like one of the most horrible things you could ever have to do.

Comment: @Voo That was pretty much the point of the first sentence in my answer :) It is similar to translating idioms literally in spoken languages: decent chances are that you would be understood, especially when an idiom evokes graphic images that are not tied to a particular culture, but, doing so would unmistakably identify you as a foreigner.

Comment: A function with tail call recursion can be converted just about mechanically to an iterative version (function arguments <=> local variables, a do {} while (true) wrapper around the whole thing, and return replaced appropriately with continue). By the same token, jiggering the recursion into tail call position is usually a matter of adding "accumulators" to the argument list. When such conversions are possible, there is no real difference.

Comment: @arayq2 Exactly - that is the reason why I said that it may not matter in the end: most compilers these days are smart enough to deal with the mechanical part of optimizing out the tail recursion for you.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I can say that for any algorithm the iterative version is always faster than the recursive. The recursive version may also lead to overflow, as the length of the recursion is limited. But, one advantage that the recursive implementations have, is that they are really simple.

Comment: Aristophan , We recently studied the C language PCRE(Perl Compatible Regular Expression) library code which uses recursion to process regular expressions. The PCRE author uses recusrion heavily but lets the user of the pCRE library specifythe maximum stack depth. Thank you for your comment